# updating database entries

Tags: php, database

Maybe ive been sat infront of the computer for too long but I cant seem to solve the following issue.

I am trying to select from a database based on a users id. I have hard coded it in and it works e.g.

```
$q = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1';
```

but when I use $_GET['id'] i get an error

```
$q = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $_GET[id] LIMIT 1';
//mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given...
```

when I get this error the address bar shows

```
update.php?id=1
```

and when I simply echo $_GET['id'] that works. So why doesn't $_GET['id'] work in my query? Ive also tried setting it as a variable prior to inputting it straight into the query but that has also failed.

Comment: try to encapsulate that way `$q = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '". $_GET[id]."' LIMIT 1';`

Comment: be aware that you are ready for `mysql injection`

Comment: Obviously I had been staring at it too long. That worked, as for sql injection, I will be sorting that once I have got this part done. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would try $q = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '.$_GET[id].' LIMIT 1';

Answer (score 0):

try
  `$q = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '.$_GET[id].' LIMIT 1';`